# Jquery Validation Engine Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, regex-negation

I'm using jQuery to validate an input form. I have values in my input boxes Name, Telephone etc which are ghost hints as guides for the user.

My issue arises with the jQuery validation, as it is recognising this ghost text as an input, and therefore processing the form before the user enters anything.

Input Field:

```
<input class="validate[required,custom[name]] text-input" type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="Name" onfocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value=''; " onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
```

Regex in Validation Engine js file:

```
"name":{
    "regex":"/(Name)$/",
    "alertText":"Please enter your name"},
```

My goal is this:

if input field = "Name" {display JS error}
else: process field

How would I do this to match "Name". Additional Question: I also have input fields with multiple words as ghost text such as "Your Phone Number". Would the Regex be different for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite correct Tom - we are getting our wires crossed - You effectively want to *negate the regex* so use...

```
/^(?!^Name$).*$/
```

This uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match anything (ie validate anything) *other than* `Name`.

Likewise for the phone number one...

```
/^(?!^Your Phone Number$).*$/
```

Of course, these won't actually validate that they are valid names (what are they ? :)) or valid phone numbers just that they *aren't* `Name` or `Your Phone Number` *exactly*...

Comment: I've tried that, but still I'm getting the error popping up...
"name":{
 "regex":"/^Name$/",
 "alertText":"Please enter your name"},

Comment: Thanks For your help El Ronnoco, after trying again the error is in reverse - If I put 'Name' into the field it doesn't error, but anything else it does. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more code? Or even better create a demo on jsFiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Here's a demo...http://bit.ly/MmBRJZ

No validation when 'name is unchanged' and validation when it is changed. It's the reverse of what I want to happen.

Comment: I think we may be getting our wires crossed slightly here, but I appreciate your help.

I'm trying to only validate when the name field equals Name. If there's anything else entered then I would like NO validation. It appears the Fiddle you created does the opposite. Any way to reverse it?

Comment: Perfect. I searched high and low for this on the internet and it proved remarkably difficult to find. Thanks a HUGE amount El Ronnoco.

Comment: @Tom No probs Tom - Glad your first question on SO had a successful conclusion! Thanks for the tick :) If you'd have googled 'Negating an entire regular expression' you'd have had more luck ;)